# Visual Studio 2019 Professional IDE icons missing after installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My tech support gave me the VS 2019 professional exe. I ran the exe as an administrator but I don't see any of the VS IDE icons loaded. I am not sure whats the issue, can it be the VPN network that is preventing the download of the icons.
I also disconnected VPN and a fresh installation but no luck.
Please help me as I am stuck on this for past 2 days.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the Visual Studio Installer's "Repair" feature to ensure all components are installed correctly.

If that doesn't work, use the "Report a Problem" feature in VS itself to report the issue to Microsoft so someone can investigate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working, issue was related to wrong OneDrive configured by the admin team, once he changed the OneDrive configuration everything is working as expected